# My column content is wrapping to a new column mid-content

Tags: css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

I have 4 articles that I cannot put in blocks (in section, div, or whatever) because they are generated by PHP code (I am developing a WordPress template and these articles are the posts written by the admin for a specific category). And I want to display these articles [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVqgu.jpg), i.e. two articles per column, whatever the height of them may be.

So, as I can't wrap them into blocks, I used a multicolumn-layout property:

```css
#main_contact {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="wrapper">
    <main id="main_contact">
<!--
Id catégorie Contact : 6
Id catégorie Communication parentale : 4
Id catégorie Art-thérapie : 5
Id catégorie Accueil : 3
Id catégorie Non classé : 1
-->
      <?php
      global $post;
      $args = array( 'numberposts' => 999, 'category' => 6, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC',);
      $myposts = get_posts( $args );
      foreach( $myposts as $post ) :                                     setup_postdata($post); 
      ?>
      <article id="id<?php the_id()?>">
        <div class="contenu">
          <h2>
          <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
          <!--Génère une balise img avec alt prenant nom de l'image-->
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?>
          <p><?php the_id()?></p>
          <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
            
 </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!--wrapper-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But this is the result:

[image]

The bottom of the second article that should be at the end of the first column is found at the top of the second column (because the height of the first two articles is higher than the two other ones).

How can I manage the height of these two columns (knowing that a `column-height` property doesn't exist) to display my two articles per column?

Maybe the solution is to apply the height of the higher pair of articles to the two columns but how?

I tried to use the flexbox stretch property but it doesn't work; maybe I misused it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your snippet doesn't match the "this is the result" image.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I wanted to show my code with the php code. But here people can have the result : http://codepen.io/chauvel-h/pen/PbNrXX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop my column content from wrapping to a new column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962174/how-can-i-stop-my-column-content-from-wrapping-to-a-new-column)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to set article display option to inline-block:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoaYxz

```
<style>
    #main_contact {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }

    article {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <main id="main_contact">
      <article id="id1">
        <div class="contenu">
          <h2>
         title 1</h2>
          <!--Génère une balise img avec alt prenant nom de l'image-->

          <p>1eeee111111111</p>
          <p>1eee2232323</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article id="id2">
        <div class="contenu">
          <h2>
         title 2</h2>
          <!--Génère une balise img avec alt prenant nom de l'image-->

          <p>22222</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article id="id3">
        <div class="contenu">
          <h2>
         title 3</h2>
          <!--Génère une balise img avec alt prenant nom de l'image-->

          <p>333333</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article id="id4">
        <div class="contenu">
          <h2>
         title 4</h2>
          <!--Génère une balise img avec alt prenant nom de l'image-->

          <p>44444444444</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!--wrapper-->
```

Comment: Thank you. For your example it works, but when an article is too high compared to the others, it doesn't. http://codepen.io/chauvel-h/pen/PbNrXX 
But I am trying to find a solution with this basis.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be helpful to you.

```css
.maincontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 150vh;
  max-width: 250vw;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
.row:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20vw;
}
.row:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30vw;
}
.row:nth-child(1) .item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 50vh;
}
.row:nth-child(1) .item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 100vh;
}
.row:nth-child(2) .item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 30vh;
}
.row:nth-child(2) .item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Tarifs</div>
    <div class="item">voir</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">directment</div>
    <div class="item">formula</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I cannot wrap my articles in `<div>` because they are generated by a php code.